# GCD and exponentiation of large numbers

Tags: exponentiation, gcd-and-lcm

I am solving a problem involving $\gcd$ of two very large numbers. Given three numbers $a,b,n$, I have to find $\gcd(a,b^n)$. So for example
$$a,b,n=119929244861828206, 521483382396998375, 4838134431180356$$
I used fast modular exponentiation to find
$$521483382396998375^{4838134431180356}\bmod 1000000007=473264774$$
Then I used python's `math.gcd` module to calculate $\gcd(119929244861828206,473264774)$ and got the answer as 2 but the answer is given as 83. I am not sure what mistake I did, so please guide me.

Comment: Why did you reduce it mod $100000000007$?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Presumably because of https://www.codechef.com/AUG18B/problems/GCDMOD

Comment: $n $ is large enough to be irrelevent.  If $a $ and $b $ have any prime factor $p $ in common and $p^k $ divides $a $ then $k <n $ and $p^k|b^n $ and the highest power in the gcd has to be whatever the highest power dividing $a $ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Euclidean algorithm, the first step can be chosen to be computing $b^n$ mod $a$, then compute $a$ mod that, etc. until you get 0. Then back up a step to get the actual GCD, then finally mod by 1000000007 at the end.

Modding by the final modulus at the start changes the result compared to doing it at the end. For instance consider that gcd(11,4) mod 3 is 1 but gcd(11 mod 3,4) is 2.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also point out the possible cause my solution is not producing the intended result?

Comment: @Vishal.R Done.